How to change quality on youtube api video
when i change quality it doesnt work and always get one quality , i want to change quality dynamically .... this is my code..
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>YouTube API Example</title>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script>
        var player;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '360',
                width: '640',
                videoId: 'yOYF4VtXXP8', // Replace with your video ID
                playerVars: {
                    'autoplay': 0,
                    'controls': 1,
                    'rel': 0,
                    'showinfo': 0
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });
        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        function changeQuality(quality) {
            player.setPlaybackQuality(quality);
            var currentQuality = player.getPlaybackQuality();
            console.log("Current quality: " + currentQuality);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <button onclick="changeQuality('small')">Low Quality</button>
    <button onclick="changeQuality('medium')">Medium Quality</button>
    <button onclick="changeQuality('large')">High Quality</button>
    <button onclick="changeQuality('hd720')">HD 720p</button>
    <button onclick="changeQuality('hd1080')">HD 1080p</button>
    <button onclick="changeQuality('highres')">High Resolution</button>

   
</body>
</html>

i tried many times , but no use. video starts with tiny quality ,when i click any button i get tiny quaity

It seems is not possible - see this answer.

Does this answer your question? How I can set quality resolution on YouTube video with react-native-youtube-iframe?
